# Get $_GET value

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a simple PHP program. I am trying to get the value from the URL and check if the dev is equal to true. I am using this code:

```
if($_GET['dev']==true){...}else if($_GET['dev']==false){...}
```

Comment: not enough code/information to support the question.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Need more information about your problem, at a guess is your URL formatted correctly? i.e. `example.com?dev=true`

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a look at this [guide on how to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that we can better help you out.

Comment: @MarcB They want us to all join in their game of charades. and I suck at that game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_GET` variable are all strings, you will need to cast it to a boolean

```
if (isset($_GET['dev']))
{
    $dev= (bool) $_GET['dev'];
    if($dev){

    }
}
```

Comment: which doesn't help much. this would work exactly the same as OP's `== true`. php will cast $_GET['dev'] to bool for the `==` test, using the exact same rules that the `(bool)` typecast would use.

Comment: Personally Meda, I'd check more if `empty()` rather than `isset()`. `isset()` may fail. Or both `isset()` and `!empty()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes indeed they are very similar, I think `isset` does not catch the empty strings, Idk why I always use it instead if empty

Comment: @meda you're right, `isset()` does not. `empty()` checks for both (isset/empty).

Comment: @Fred-ii- I like `isset()` because you can check multiple value once, `isset($_GET['1'],$_GET['2'],$_GET['3'])` but I see how empty could be more useful, I should use it more

Answer (score -2):

details are not enough, tell us more about your problem.

maybe you need to compare dev to a string and not to boolean:

```
  if($_GET['dev']=="true"){...}else if($_GET['dev']=="false"){...}
```

Comment: `"true"` - `"false"` are treated as strings here and will fail on boolean constants - which I kind of doubt is what OP wants to do here.

Comment: i think that He is looking if the value of dev is "true" or "false" , as strings ,

Comment: that's not my downvote btw. We asked for clarification in comments but they're not responding and expecting a magic answer.

Comment: It makes absolute no sense to check for the value as strings.... In this case you would check for 2 values or boolean..

Comment: yes maybe, we still don't have clarification about the problem

Comment: This is also a right answer.